# Reduce space between app logo and app name on action bar in android

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I have action bar along with app logo and app name.
So I want to reduce space between app logo and app name.
Below I have attached some screenshot.

A)  **Action bar I have**

[image]

B)  **Action bar I want**

[image]

Comment: use toolbarLayout add linearlayout with horizontal orientation as child view to it. inside linearlayout add logo with imageview and app name with textview with width wrapcontent and `android:layout_weight="1"` for both.

Comment: Are u using toolBar ?

Comment: @Redman yes i am

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Toolbar` for this, it will provide greater customization.

**Here is the sample example.**

**toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- This is a centered logo -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_logo"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <!-- This is a centered title -->
        <!--
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse"
            />
            -->

        <!-- This is a custom left side button -->
        <!--
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_settings"
            android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_marginRight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_white_24dp"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton" />
            -->

        <!-- This is a custom right side button -->
        <!--
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_search"
            android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_magnify_white_24dp"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton" />
            -->

    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Add any view inside toolbar as it is a viewgroup. Hopw this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)
```

Comment: it will disable back button not space between title and title logo

Comment: Answer which was given by Rahul chandrabhan help me to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <include layout="@layout/header_with_back"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**header_with_back.xml code**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
     android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
     android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_back_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/threedp"
        android:padding="@dimen/tendp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_title_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image_back_header"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/tendp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/tendp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/twentydp"
        android:maxLength="26"
        android:text="dsdsdsa"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_18"
        android:typeface="normal"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_right_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_16"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/tendp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/tendp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/tendp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/fifteendp"
        android:text="@string/save"
        android:typeface="normal"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java code**

```
Toolbar toolbar; 
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);//for tab otherwise give space in tab
        toolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these properties to toolBar

```
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
```

final toolbar should be something like this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@drawable/paper9patch"
app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks..for your help